# How to explain that this line is perpendicular to this one?

Tags: geometry

I have got this figure :
[image: IFJ triangle, with IF = FJ]
It is obvious that (FK) is perpendicular to (IJ), but I can't explain, with a simple sentence, why it is like this...

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triangles $FIK$ and $FJK$ are congruent, so $\angle FKI=\angle FKJ$, but $\angle FKI+\angle FKJ=\pi$, so $\angle FKI =\angle FKJ =\frac{\pi}{2}$, leading to $FK$ being perpendicular to $IJ$.

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream Yes, thanks. just changed the answer.

Comment: You are welcome.